# "Infinite" (max int) CSS only counter

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do an **"infinite (max int 2147483647)"** counter in CSS only, I cannot use javascript or other languages, I have succeeded via @property but it is only supported on Chrome, Edge and Opera.
Is there any way to achieve this without using javascript and without writing all the numbers in HTML?

```
@property --num { syntax: "<integer>"; initial-value: 0; inherits: false; }
.counter { counter-set: num var(--num); }
.counter::after { content: counter(num); }
.counter { animation: counter 2147483647s linear infinite; }
@keyframes counter { to { --num: 2147483647; } }
```

If not possible can you suggest a way to detect current and future browsers that supports **@property**
In my mind there is something like

```
@support (@property) { /* CSS HERE */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping something involving steps would work, but of course it doesn't.

So I think the answer is that there isn't an obvious way of doing this on browsers which don't support the @property rule

However, you can (sort of) detect the browser by using @supports on a property/value which is supported also by Chromium-type browsers but not by Safari or Firefox.

Thanks to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/bramus/status/1409978605204119553?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1409978605204119553%7Ctwgr%5E%7Ctwcon%5Es1_&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bram.us%2F2021%2F06%2F23%2Fcss-at-supports-rules-to-target-only-firefox-safari-chromium%2F) for suggesting using background-image: paint(...)

```css
@property --num {
  syntax: "<integer>";
  initial-value: 0;
  inherits: false;
}

.counter::after {
  content: 'I have a feeling I do not support @property';
}

@supports (background-image: paint(thingo)) {
  .counter {
    counter-set: num var(--num);
  }
  .counter::after {
    content: counter(num);
  }
  .counter {
    animation: counter 2147483647s linear infinite;
  }
  @keyframes counter {
    to {
      --num: 2147483647;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="counter"></div>
```

I say 'sort of' because I suppose there might come a time when say FF supports one not the other.